# How to use cross join with left outer join?

Tags: mysql

I have to show list of employee who has claim for expense for the particular month, but am getting all employee list.

```
SELECT employee_id, expense_month, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('=', exp_type_text, monthly_exployee_expense))
FROM
(
SELECT tbl_employee.employee_id, expense_months.expense_month, tbl_expense_type.exp_type_id, tbl_expense_type.exp_type_text, SUM(expense_cost) AS monthly_exployee_expense
FROM tbl_employee
CROSS JOIN tbl_expense_type
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(expense_date, '%Y%m') AS expense_month
    FROM exp_tbl
) expense_months
LEFT OUTER JOIN exp_tbl
ON tbl_employee.employee_id = exp_tbl.employee_id
AND tbl_expense_type.exp_type_id = some_table.expense_type
AND expense_months.expense_month = DATE_FORMAT(exp_tbl.expense_date, '%Y%m')
GROUP BY tbl_employee.employee_id, expense_months.expense_month, tbl_expense_type.exp_type_id, tbl_expense_type.exp_type_text
) Sub1
GROUP BY employee_id, expense_month
```

this the query i had.. how to get only expense claimed employee list.

Example out put is:

```
3   Ramesh Kumar M  201402  Phone Expense=0=16,Consumable Purchase=0=11,Auto=0...
3   Ramesh Kumar M  201403  Consumable Purchase=0=11,Auto=0=6,2 wheeler=0=1,Lo...
3   Ramesh Kumar M  201404  Logistics/Transportation=0=18,Labour=0=13,Fuel=0=8...
3   Ramesh Kumar M  201405  Bus Travel=0=3,Office Vehicle=0=20,Others=0=15,Sta...
4   testexplevel1   201402  Others=0=15,Stay=0=10,Train Travel=0=5,Office Main...
4   testexplevel1   201403  Office Maintenance=0=17,Billable Purchase=0=12,Cal...
4   testexplevel1   201404  Call Taxi=0=7,4 wheeler=0=2,Guest House=0=19,Trans...
```

In that list not want all employee list. Only show ramesh data. Because that employee only has claimed.

Comment: Any sample and expected result set ?

Comment: Ramesh M 201402 Phone Expense=0=16,Consumable,..
Ramesh M 201403 Consumable Purchase=0=11,Auto=0=6,2..
Ramesh M 201404 logistics/Transportation=0=18,Labour=0=13..
testexplevel1 201402 Others=0=15,Stay=0=10,Train .. testexplevel1 201403 Office Maintenance=0=17,Billable ..
testexplevel1 201404 Call Taxi=0=7,4 wheeler=0=2,Guest..           This list contains all employee list. Only want ramesh data.. not want testexplevel1 data.. because that employee doesn't claimed any expenses.

Comment: Please update your question do not post data set in comments

Comment: Not only output, we also need to see the input.

Comment: Right.. I did all user data and used cross join with actual expenses for getting list. Now i want claimed user list only.. means some what to change in my query to achieve my requirement, but dnt know how to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense. You cross join all employees against all months and all expense types into a big cartesian product. Then you `left join` the actual expenses, so nothing gets excluded if there are no expenses.

So the quick fix would be to `inner join` the expenses. Doing so only gives you the employee-months for which an expense exists.

But doing so also allows you to remove the cross joins altogether and change it all to inner joins:

```
select
  emp.employee_id,
  DATE_FORMAT(ex.expense_date, '%Y%m'),
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('=', et.exp_type_text, ex.monthly_exployee_expense))
from
  tbl_employee emp
  inner join exp_tbl ex on ex.employee_id = emp.employee_id
  inner join tbl_expense_type et on et.exp_type_id = ex.expense_type
group by
  emp.employee_id,
  DATE_FORMAT(ex.expense_date, '%Y%m')
```

Now, isn't that query much cleaner? :)